# dispatchEvent no funciona

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer triger a un evento click.

he recogido el elemento al que quiero hacerle click de las siguientes formas:

```javascript
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('s-btn d-block');
```

y

```javascript
let element = document.querySelector("a.s-btn.d-block");
```

de cualquier forma al usar `console.log(element)` obtento esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al intentar ejecutar un `dispatchEvent` de esta forma:

```javascript
let click = new MouseEvent('click', {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        });
element[0].dispatchEvent(click);
```

obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se que esta mal o que esta provocando el error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación, [`getElementsByClassName( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) devuelve un [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection); el cual, si bien es similar, **no** es un *Array*. Para acceder a sus elementos, has de usar el método `item( )`.

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName( 's-btn d-block' );

let click = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
} );
element.item( 0 ).dispatchEvent( click );
```

En el caso de [`querySelector( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), esta devuelve **un único elemento**:

```
let element = document.querySelector("a.s-btn.d-block");

let click = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
} );
element.dispatchEvent( click );
```

Comment: cual de los dos me recomiendas???

Comment: solo me funciona la segunda opción XD